# Erlang List concatenation, weird "|" sign

Tags: list, erlang, concatenation, bubble-sort

in order to become familar with Erlang, i'm trying
to write my own Bubblesort Algorithm. Right now, i have
the following code in my module:

```
-module(mysort).
-export([bubblesort/1]).

bubblesort(L) ->
    sort_sequence(L, []).

sort_sequence([H1|[H2|T]], Sorted) ->
    if H2 >= H1 ->
        sort_sequence(T, Sorted ++ [H1, H2]);
    H2 < H1 ->
        sort_sequence(T, Sorted ++ [H2, H1])
    end;
sort_sequence([H|T], Sorted) ->
    Sorted ++ H;
sort_sequence([], Sorted) ->
    Sorted.
```

first of all: **please don't give me suggestions to my code**
i want to figure it out myself ^^

the problem is: if i say `mysort:bubblesort([2,1,3,4,5]).`
the output is as i would expect: `[1,2,3,4,5]`

but if i say `mysort:bubblesort([2,1,3,5,4]).`
the output is: `[1,2,3,5|4].`

my only question is: **what does this "|" sign mean in between the listitems ?!**

thank you all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list can have two forms: Either it is empty (`[]`), or it has a head and a tail (`[H|T]`). So `[]` is an empty list, `[1 | []]` is a list whose head is 1 and whose tail is `[]`, and `[1|2]` is a list whose head is 1 and whose tail is 2.

A list is called a *proper* list if it is empty or its tail is a proper list. So `[]` is a proper list because its empty and `[1|[]]` is a proper list because its tail is the empty list (which is a proper list), but `[1|2]` is not a proper list because its tail is 2 and 2 is not a proper list.

Since proper lists are the most common types of lists and reading and writing them as nested lists like that is kind of cumbersome, there's a special syntax for them: A proper list is displayed and can be written by separating the heads of the sublists with commas. So if we have the proper list `[1 | [2 | [3 | []]]]` it is displayed as `[1,2,3]` (and we can also write it that way), which is much more readable.

This format is also used to display the beginning of improper lists if they "start out" proper up to the point where the non-proper tail is, which will be separated with a `|`. So for example if we have the improper list `[1 | [2 | [3|4]]]` (which is improper because the innermost tail is 4, which is not a proper list), it will be displayed as `[1,2,3|4]` to distinguish it from the proper list `[1 | [2 | [ 3 | [4 | []]]]]`, which would be displayed as `[1,2,3,4]`.

So if you see something like that, you somehow created a list whose tail is not a proper list.

Comment: thanks man, you explained it well :-) Coming from Languages like C, Java and Python, Erlang is my first functional Language (even though Python can be programmed functional as well) and it totally f***s my brain up <_<

Answer (score 5):

This occurs when tail not list:

```
> [1,2,3 | 2].
[1,2,3|2]

> [1,2,3 | [2]].
[1,2,3,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

first: thank you guys !

```
sort_sequence([H|T], Sorted) ->
    Sorted ++ H;
```

i concated a single item to the list which is of course
not a proper list; which resulted into the error you 
both explained